# XPath/XQuery: Select a root node with its attributes without childs

Tags: xslt, xpath, xquery, root-node, xquery-sql

I have an xml:

```
<Customer id="">
 <Name />
 <Address />
</Customer>
```

I would like to select ONLY a root node with its attributes without its child nodes:

```
<Customer id=""/ >
```

Is such thing possible with XPath?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a short XSLT solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in XPath.

You can't **select** the node without its children, because without its children it would be a different node, hence you would not be selecting a node from the original document.

To create the output you want you need to use a language which allows you to create new nodes, so you can't do it in XPath. You can use XQuery to create new nodes, this should work:

```
element {fn:node-name(/*)} {/*/@*}
```

Answer (score 2):

**XPath does not alter any source XML document and this is by design**.

To produce a new XML document from an existing one, *transformation* is needed.

XSLT has been especially designed for transforming a set of trees (including XML documents) into result trees.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Customer id="">
    <Name />
    <Address />
</Customer>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Customer id=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($str);

$xPath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xPathQuery = "//text()[contains(translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), '<Customer id=\"\">')]";
$elements = $xPath->query($xPathQuery);

if($elements->length > 0){

foreach($elements as $element){
    print "Found: " .$element->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanx for an answer, but I need XPath construct, since I do the stuff in T-SQL. Something like: select @XmlData.query('/[nochildrenhere]')

Comment: Aah ok, then i can't help you, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

This XQuery expression:

```
element {name(/*)} {/*/@*}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Customer id=""/>
```